# getMapAsync error - Google maps api android

Tags: java, android, json, google-maps

So Im trying to display markers on my map from a Jsonfile and they are not appearing Ive narrowed it down to the line

```
map = mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

it gives me the error

> Incompatible types:
>   Required: com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap Found: Void

Here is the rest of the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
private static final String LOG_TAG = "ExampleApp";

private static final String SERVICE_URL = "https://api.myjson.com/bins/4jb09";

protected GoogleMap map;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}

private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    if (map == null) {
        MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        map = mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        if (map != null) {
            //setUpMap();
            new MarkerTask().execute();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    map = googleMap;
    setUpMap();
}

private void setUpMap() {
    // Retrieve the city data from the web service
    // In a worker thread since it's a network operation.
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                retrieveAndAddCities();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Cannot retrive cities", e);
                return;
            }
        }
    }).start();
}

protected void retrieveAndAddCities() throws IOException {
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    final StringBuilder json = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        // Connect to the web service
        URL url = new URL(SERVICE_URL);
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());

        // Read the JSON data into the StringBuilder
        int read;
        char[] buff = new char[1024];
        while ((read = in.read(buff)) != -1) {
            json.append(buff, 0, read);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error connecting to service", e);
        throw new IOException("Error connecting to service", e);
    } finally {
        if (conn != null) {
            conn.disconnect();
        }
    }

    // Create markers for the city data.
    // Must run this on the UI thread since it's a UI operation.
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                createMarkersFromJson(json.toString());
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error processing JSON", e);
            }
        }
    });
}

void createMarkersFromJson(String json) throws JSONException {
    // De-serialize the JSON string into an array of city objects
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        // Create a marker for each city in the JSON data.
        JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .title(jsonObj.getString("name"))
                .snippet(Integer.toString(jsonObj.getInt("population")))
                .position(new LatLng(
                        jsonObj.getJSONArray("latlng").getDouble(0),
                        jsonObj.getJSONArray("latlng").getDouble(1)
                ))
        );
    }
}



private class MarkerTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = "ExampleApp";

    private static final String SERVICE_URL = "https://api.myjson.com/bins/4jb09";

    // Invoked by execute() method of this object
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... args) {

        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        final StringBuilder json = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            // Connect to the web service
            URL url = new URL(SERVICE_URL);
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());

            // Read the JSON data into the StringBuilder
            int read;
            char[] buff = new char[1024];
            while ((read = in.read(buff)) != -1) {
                json.append(buff, 0, read);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error connecting to service", e);
            //throw new IOException("Error connecting to service", e); //uncaught
        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.disconnect();
            }
        }

        return json.toString();
    }

    // Executed after the complete execution of doInBackground() method
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String json) {

        try {
            // De-serialize the JSON string into an array of city objects
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(jsonObj.getJSONArray("latlng").getDouble(0),
                        jsonObj.getJSONArray("latlng").getDouble(1));

                //move CameraPosition on first result
                if (i == 0) {
                    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                            .target(latLng).zoom(13).build();

                    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                            .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
                }

                // Create a marker for each city in the JSON data.
                map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE))
                        .title(jsonObj.getString("name"))
                        .snippet(Integer.toString(jsonObj.getInt("population")))
                        .position(latLng));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error processing JSON", e);
        }

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Change it to

```
map.getMapAsync(this);
```

instead of

```
map = mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

because

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
this.googleMap = googleMap; 

}
```

return type of this method is void, so it will not return anything.
You have to do this:

```
map.getMapAsync(this)
```

Answer (score 0):

mapFragment.getMapAsync(this); has return type **Void**
Change your **setUpMapIfNeeded()** to following one

```
private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    if (map == null) {
        MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }
}
```

Do the marker setting work in onMapReady().

Answer (score 0):

Use SupportMapFragment instead of MapFragment.You can take help from following code sample.

Define MapFragment as :

```
private SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment; 
GoogleMap mGoogleMap; //for google map
```

And in your activity creation, you can do like this:

```
if(supportMapFragment==null){
        supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
                mGoogleMap = googleMap;

                //do load your map and other map stuffs here...
            }
        });
```

hope this will help you ...

Answer (score 0):

Your code is returning this error `Incompatible types: Required: com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap Found: Void`

because [`getMapAsync()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment) does not return anything. If you look at the documentation for this function:

[public void getMapAsync (OnMapReadyCallback callback)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment#getMapAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback))

Sets a callback object which will be triggered when the GoogleMap instance is ready to be used.

**Note:**

This method must be called from the main thread. The callback will be executed in the main thread. In the case where Google Play services is not installed on the user's device, the callback will not be triggered until the user installs it. In the rare case where the GoogleMap is destroyed immediately after creation, the callback is not triggered. The GoogleMap object provided by the callback is non-null.
OnMapReadyCallback is an interface that needs implemented and passed to through this function. Nothing is currently assigned to your googleMap variable you should instead set its value in this block of code which implements **OnMapReadyCallback**

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
this.googleMap = googleMap; 

}
```